# Search for multiple user supplied terms in db column

Tags: sql, postgresql

How do I search for multiple user supplied terms in db column while still properly escaping them?  I want this but with proper escaping:

```
select * from foo where description like '%<user term>%'
```

If I do:

```
select * from foo where description like $1
```

then I'm not sure how to insert the %'s around the user's term.

Answer (score 0):

just use `%user term%`, eg:

```
t=# create role "weird name";
CREATE ROLE
t=# prepare s(text) as select rolname from pg_roles where rolname like $1;
PREPARE
t=# execute s('%rd na%');
  rolname
------------
 weird name
(1 row)
```